# How to import classes from `com.android.build.api.transform` package in Maven

Tags: maven, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, gradle-plugin, maven-dependency

I am trying to transfer a gradle-based build plugin for android to a maven build system.
Up to now I was successful except with the android part.

It seems that I am missing classes from the package `com.android.build.api.transform`. Although I used this code

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.tools.build</groupId>
        <artifactId>gradle</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

which is supposed to provide (rather indirectly) the required classes/packages, it seems that this is not working.

I also added

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>android</id>
        <name>android</name>
        <url>https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

just in case, with no luck. Still the project is not able to compile due to missing classes.

Any idea what I am missing? I am very new to the gradle/maven scene, and I still feel out of my waters with these tools.

For reference [here is a link](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/javadoc/1.5/index.html?com/android/build/api/transform/package-summary.html) to the javadoc of this artifact.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'gradle' artifact does not contain the missing package. As you mention, it depends transitively on at least one artifact that contains that package, but only in scope 'runtime'. Hence, it will not be available to your project on the compile classpath.

Anyway, adding the dependency explicitly in your pom.xml is the right thing to do. A search for the missing package on [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Acom.android.build.api.transform) shows that you have the choice between com.android.tools.build:transform-api and com.android.tools.build:gradle-api. Locking at the transform-api artifact reveals that it's deprecated and encourages to use gradle-api instead. (The latest version is '2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api'). I downloaded the gradle-api jar file, which indeed has the missing package. So please try adding that artifact to your pom.xml instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.tools.build</groupId>
    <artifactId>gradle-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I didn't check version 2.2.0, but if you for some reason want to use the older version, it will probably work too.

Comment: Indeed it appears there. Still, it seems that it has some missing dependencies. It looks like the actual functionality is well hidden

Answer (score 0):

the transform API was a Google's Android Gradle plugin technology. but it was absorbed into and expanded by Gradle. so newer Android plugins migrated to the Gradle API and they no longer include the transform engine, which now is part of Gradle. if you use the deprecated transform API from Google that was bundled with older plugins, you will get the engine. but what you plan to do about all the other dependencies on Gradle, i have no idea.